# Find all the post from my friends

Tags: facebook, posts

Is it possible that I can get ALL the posts from my friends via API in facebook? I mean All because I need all of them to search if it contains a keywork. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can search an individual user's News Feed, restricted to that user's friends, by adding a q argument to the home connection URL:

```
News Feed: https://graph.facebook.com/me/home?q={KEY}

https://graph.facebook.com/me/home?q={QUERY}&access_token={ACCESS_TOKEN}

Eg: https://graph.facebook.com/me/home?q=facebook&access_token=######
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by using the following [FQL](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/stream/) query:

```
SELECT post_id, message FROM stream WHERE source_id IN 
(SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()) LIMIT 5000
```

But you need a valid Access Token with an extended **read_stream** permission. For testing your FQL queries, you can use [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?fql=SELECT%20post_id,%20message%20FROM%20stream%20WHERE%20source_id%20IN%20%28SELECT%20uid2%20FROM%20friend%20WHERE%20uid1%20=%20me%28%29%29%20LIMIT%205000).